# Compare string to 2 other strings

Tags: c#, if-statement, compare

so i have this code part:

```
        private int checkErrors() {
           int error = 0;
           if (!(nether.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(nether.Text.Equals("false"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(fly.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(fly.Text.Equals("false"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(achivments.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(achivments.Text.Equals("false"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(whitelist.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(whitelist.Text.Equals("false"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(pvp.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(pvp.Text.Equals("false"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(commandBlock.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(commandBlock.Text.Equals("false"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(spawnMonster.Text.Equals("true"))) { error += 1; }
           if (!(spawnMonster.Text.Equals("false")) { error += 1; }
           return error;
        }
```

but in any way it will get me that `'error = 7'` because when one statement is true the other is false
so my question is:

Is there a way to compare 2 strings to a third string ?

other example: i have the string `userInput` and i want, if `userInput` not equals `"a"` or `"b"` to execute `error += 1;`!

Comment: Am guessing.. You mean `Text` can either be `true` or be `false` if not `error += 1`?

Comment: What do you mean in this line  'Is there a way to compare 2 strings to a third string ?'.

Comment: i have 2 fixed strings and want to compare them to a variable third string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're trying to find cases where it isn't "true" *and* it isn't "false". So something like:

```
if (spawnMonster.Text != "true" && spawnMonster.Text != "false")
{
    error++;
}
```

Alternatively, express the condition *once*, and apply it to all your strings:

```
var strings = new[] { nether.Text, fly.Text, achivments.Text, whitelist.Text
                      pvp.Text, commandBlock.Text, spawnMonster.Text };
return strings.Count(t => t != "true" && t != "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with two clauses :

```
          if (!nether.Text.Equals("true") && !nether.Text.Equals("false")) { error += 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is to create a function that accepts 2 parameters.  One parameter will be the userInput and the other parameter will be an array of values the userInput shouldn't be. It will return 1 or 0.

Example:

```
public int isBadValue(string userInput, string[] goodValues){
  if(Array.IndexOf(userInput) > -1){
       return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

And in your code you can just do something like this:

```
string[] goodValues = {"a", "b"};
error += isBadValue("s", goodValues);
```

You can easily add more good values and the function will be able to handle it.  Not sure if good values change based on input field that's why I didn't include it in the isBadValue function.